# If $g(x) = f(-x)$ then $g'(x) = -f'(-x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am doing two exercises using Derivatives.

1. Prove that if $f$ is even , then $f'(x) = -f(-x)$
2. Prove that if $f$ is odd, then $f'(x) = f'(-x)$.

Now, I found the answer for the exercises, but there is a statement : if $g(x) = f(-x)$ then $g'(x) = -f'(-x)$. How can I prove that statement using the Derrivate's Definition. I tried it, but everytime I get $g'(x) = -f'(x)$ instead of $g'(x) = -f'(-x)$.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use chain rule?

Comment: No, I can't. I am learning from Michael Spivak - Calculus and he talks about Chain Rule in the next Chapter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have $$
\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h=\frac{f(-x-h)-f(-x)}h=-\frac{f(-x-h)-f(-x)}{-h}
=-\frac{f(-x+k)-f(-x)}k
$$
where I renamed $-h$ as $k$. When $h\to0$, also $k\to0$. So, taking limits, $g'(x)=-f'(-x)$.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was at the third adaptation. I did (f(-x-h)-f(-x))/h = -(f(x+h)-f(x))/h